# List of themeable / skinable properties for ASP.NET controls?

Tags: asp.net, themes, skins

Does anyone know how or where I can find a list of properties that can be defined in a skin file for standard ASP.NET controls?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that every property is, by default, Themeable.  But, a number of properties are marked with the Themeable(false) attribute.  For example, an asp:Button has its OnClientClick property marked Themeable(false).

Don't know how to get this list up front though.  You'll get an error when you view a page and a Skin file tries to set a non-Themeable property.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you can set all properties of all controls. I just made a small test, I found that it's even possible to define the items to be displayed in a ListBox in the skin file.